# How to pass environment variable spring.main.web-application-type=SERVLET to run docker image

Tags: spring, docker

When I use docker run command, the variable "`SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE`" is right, but "`SPRING_MAIN_WEB-APPLICATION-TYPE`" does not work, how to pass "`SPRING_MAIN_WEB-APPLICATION-TYPE`" to dokcer image?

```
sudo docker run -d -e SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=product -e SPRING_MAIN_WEB-APPLICATION-TYPE=SERVLET -e SERVER_PORT=6789 --network mongo_network
```

Answer (score 0):

As [described in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding), the expected format for that environment variable is `SPRING_MAIN_WEBAPPLICATIONTYPE`.

Comment: Can't say about docker env but that's what you should do with an OS env

Comment: I am guessing the link is out of date? Docker env variables are the same as OS environment variables - the Spring application should be able to process them identically. I see the corresponding `spring.main.web-application-type` property being described in https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html under Disabling the Web Server. Could you point to the new location for the documentation for `SPRING_MAIN_WEBAPPLICATIONTYPE`? Or maybe some documentation that describes how to convert application properties into environment variables?

Comment: No, the link is not out of date. There is a table that describes how to specify a property as an ENV variable.

Answer (score 0):

I use docker ENV to get it worked, here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre
ENV TYPE NONE

COPY data.jar data.jar

CMD ["java","-jar","data.jar", "--spring.main.web-application-type=${TYPE}"]
```

then run the docker image:

```
sudo docker run -d -e SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=product -e TYPE=SERVLET -e SERVER_PORT=6789
```

hope this helps.